# Two loops in HTML Table

Tags: python, html

Hello I have a bit of problem with my HTML,

I have two loops from my python which generates every item with their respective.

Here's the code:

```
<table style="width:25%">
  <tr>
    <th>Nature of Collection</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>




  {%for nature in natures%}
 <tr>
    <td>{{nature}}</td>
 </tr>
  {% endfor %} 



      {%for amount in amounts%}
      <tr align="right">
    <td>{{amount}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}





</table>
```

How do I make it so that it gets formatted in a table properly? I already tried algning it, and fidgeting with it 
but I don't get the result I want.

I just want it to be a simple Table for example

```
Nature of Collection  |  Amount

NOC1                      1000
NOC2                      1000
```

What should I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for your case is to

```
from jinja2 import Template
```

And then

```
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Nature of Collection</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>

  {%for nature in natures %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{nature}}</td>
    <td>{{amounts[loop.index0]}}</td>
 </tr>
  {% endfor %} 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you need to add it as another `td` in the same `tr` as the `nature`. Perhaps using `enumerate` to access the index and then using the index for accessing the second array items

```html
<table style="width:25%">
  <tr>
    <th>Nature of Collection</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>

  {%for index, nature in enumerate(natures) %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{nature}}</td>
    <td>{{amounts[index]}}</td>
 </tr>
  {% endfor %} 
</table>
```

---

*Assuming that the arrays have the same number of elements and that there is a 1 to 1 relation based on their position.*

---

Alternate syntax for django  templates

```html
<table style="width:25%">
  <tr>
    <th>Nature of Collection</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>

  {%for nature in natures %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{nature}}</td>
    <td>{{amounts[forloop.counter0]}}</td>
 </tr>
  {% endfor %} 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting up a separate row for each item in your list. Rather than wrapping each value in TR tags, use one TR tag that contains the nature of collection and amount values within it, something like:

```
<tr> 
  <td>{nature of collection}</tr>
  <td>{value}</tr>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
<table style="width:25%">


<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Nature of Collection</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>

</thead>

<tbody>
 {%for nature in natures%}
```

```
<td>{{nature}}</td>
```

```
{% endfor %} 



  {%for amount in amounts%}
  <tr align="right">
<td>{{amount}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</tbody>
```